# How to set a value to single radio button in a group box containing 4 radio buttons with grideview cellclick event in c#

Tags: c#, gridview, radio-button, groupbox

How to get value from gridview and set coresponding radio button in group box?
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2] (how to get this value to a char
variable?)the values are 'V' or 'N' present in the gridview.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Selected = true;
    textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value+"";         
    textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value + "";
    comboBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value + "";
}
```

Comment: DataGridViewCellEventArgsdataGridView1. --> CurrentRow.Selected = true;
            textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value + "";
            textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value+"";
            radioButton1.Checked = 'V'.Equals(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value);
            radioButton2.Checked = 'N' .Equals(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value);
            textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value + "";
            comboBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value + "";

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the radio button that represents V is called vRadioButton etc, something like:

```
vRadioButton.Checked = "V".Equals(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[xxx].Value);
nRadioButton.Checked = "N".Equals(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[xxx].Value);
```

where `xxx`  is either the name or number of the column holding V or N

Ultimately you have to compare the in-grid value with a constant to generate a boolean abd set `Checked` to that bool

Comment: vRadioButton.Checked = "V".Equals(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[xxx].Value); the datatype is char implemented with this code but there is no change in result

Comment: what is the way for storing the value in that cell to a char variable? help me out bro

Comment: If it's a char, rather than a string, use `'V'` with single quote `'` not double `"`